# Can you set the HTTP_REFERER in PHP in any reliable way?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, http-referer

Background: I need to set `HTTP_REFERER` for a 3rd party store to recognize that the user of their store is coming from my page.

Issue: Users authenticate, which is secured over HTTPS. When sending the user from HTTPS to the HTTP custom store, standard security behavior of web browsers kick in and the `HTTP_REFERER` is lost.

Coming from HTTPS, is there any way to set the `HTTP_REFERER` value reliably?

Comment: You can send raw headers with `header()` function. `header('Referer: http://your.site.com');header('Location: http://silly.insecure.store.com');`

Comment: Are you 100% sure it works? I've done some testing after I posted the answer and I'm not getting the referer I set. Jani was right with his answer, so I wouldn't want to post something that's not the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use CURL, the headers you set using it are *only* used by CURL's own request functionality. It has absolutely no effect on the user's browser.

The same with `header()`. It will only set *response headers* to the current request from the user's browser.

There is *no way* to set the referrer header the user's browser should  use in the next request from PHP.

Assuming you were to perform the entire request using CURL, and then echoing the results of the request, it should work. But besides that, no.